# Why is my TCP socket showing connected but not responding?

Tags: sockets, tcp, vb6

I have a program using a bi-directional TCP socket to send messages from the host PC to a VLinx ethernet-to-serial converter and then on to a PLC via RS-232.  During heavy traffic the socket will intermittently stop communicating although all soft tests of the connection show that it is connected, active and writeable.  I suspect that something is interrupting the connection causing the socket to close with out FIN/ACK.  How can I test to see where this disconnect might be occuring?

The program itself is written in VB6 and uses Catalyst SocketTools/SocketWrench as opposed to the standard Winsock library.  The methodology, properties and code seem to be sound since the same setup works reliably at two other sites.  It's just this one site in particular where this problem occurs.  It only happens during production when there is traffic on the network and can lose connection anywhere between 20 - 100 times per 10-hour day.

There are redundant tests in place to catch this loss of communication and keep the system running.  We have tests on ACK messages, message queue size, time between transmissions (tokens on 2s interval), etc.  Typically, the socket will not be unresponsive for more than 30 seconds before it is caught, closed and re-established which works properly >99% of the time.

Previously I had enabled the SocketTools logging capabilities which did not capture any relevant information.  Most recently I have tried to have the system ping the VLinx on the first sign of a missed message (2.5 seconds).  Those pings have always been successful, meaning that if there is a momentary loss of connection at a switch or AP it does not stay disconnected for long.

I do not have access to the network hardware aside from the PC and VLinx that we own.  The facility's IT is also not inclined to help track these kinds of things down because they work on a project-based model.

Does anyone have any suggestions what I can do to try and determine where the problem is occurring so that I can then try to come up with a permanent solution to this issue rather than the band-aid of reconnecting multiple times per day?

Comment: Use `netstat -t` to determine offload state and then try to disable TCP Chimney Offload by googling the correct `netsh` incantation.

Answer (score 0):

A tool like Wireshark may be helpful in seeing what's going on at the network level. The logging facility in SocketTools/SocketWrench can only report what's going on at the API level, and it sounds like whatever the underlying problem is occurs at a lower level in the TCP stack.

If this is occurring after periods of relative inactivity, followed by a burst of activity, one thing you could try doing is enabling keep-alive and see if that makes any difference.